# Pass arguments to a user space thread

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I have experimented with a userspace thread using C++. In the current version of the code, I am only able to point stack pointer to a specific function pointer but not sure how to place arguments.

Here is the basic implementation without function argument for the child thread. In the current implementation, I kept only two threads.

```
// File: main.cpp
/* Ubuntu 18.04 **x86_64** */
/* Compiler gcc version 7.5.0 */
/* Linux 5.6.2 */
/* g++ -g -std=c++11 main.cpp ContextSwitch.S */

#include <iostream>

const int __stack_size = 1 << 20;       // 1 MB


#define PrintF printf("%d : %s\n",__LINE__,__FUNCTION__);


// A Set of Registers to Represent the Context of Thread
// These register values are presered across function calls
// in x86-64 ABI
struct Context {
    uint64_t rsp;
    uint64_t r15;
    uint64_t r14;
    uint64_t r13;
    uint64_t r12;
    uint64_t rbp;
    uint64_t rbx;
};


// This is a function defined inside an Assembly file
// According to x86-64 ABI convention
// rdi == curr and rsi == next
extern "C" void ContextSwitch(Context *curr,Context *next);


// Lets take only two Thread
static struct Context Main;
static struct Context Child;


// This function helps to get back control from Child Thread
// When Child thread completes its assigned function
// this following function will be invoked
static void sched() {
    PrintF

    // now please switch back to Main thread
    ContextSwitch(&Child,&Main);
    std::cout <<"Not Reachable !" << std::endl;

}


// Child thread is going to run this function
void func() {
    PrintF

    // some dummy calculation inside this function

    int aa[100]; // 400 Bytes
    for(int i = 0;i<100;i++) {
        if(i%20 == 0) {
            aa[i] = 2*i;
        }
    }

    // on return from this function
    // ret instruction will be called
    // due to which rip will point to the value of 
    // top 8 byte of childStack
    // which is basically sched function
}

typedef unsigned long long ULL;

int main() {

    // allocate stack memory for the Child Thread
    char * childStack = new char[__stack_size];
    

    // sched() will be pointed by rip when func() returns
    *(ULL *)&childStack[__stack_size -  8] = (ULL)sched;


    // func() will be pointed by rip just before ContextSwitch() returns below
    *(ULL *)&childStack[__stack_size -  16] = (ULL)func;


    // when ContextSwitch tries to return from the call below,
    // rsp value will be loaded in rip due to ret call
    // which makes rip == addr of func()
    Child.rsp = (uint64_t)&childStack[__stack_size - 16];

    ContextSwitch(&Main,&Child);

    std::cout <<"Main is schduled again!" << std::endl;
    delete[] childStack;
}

// File: ContextSwitch.S
.globl ContextSwitch
ContextSwitch:

        movq     %rsp, 0x00(%rdi)
        movq     %r15, 0x08(%rdi)
        movq     %r14, 0x10(%rdi)
        movq     %r13, 0x18(%rdi)
        movq     %r12, 0x20(%rdi)
        movq     %rbp, 0x28(%rdi)
        movq     %rbx, 0x30(%rdi)

        movq     0x00(%rsi), %rsp
        movq     0x08(%rsi), %r15
        movq     0x10(%rsi), %r14
        movq     0x18(%rsi), %r13
        movq     0x20(%rsi), %r12
        movq     0x28(%rsi), %rbp
        movq     0x30(%rsi), %rbx

        ret
```

This implementation executes in my machine with the following output:

```
54 : func
43 : sched
Main is schduled again!
```

Now I tried with argument `int` argument in `func()`. (Although have not actually passed anything)

```
// Child thread is going to run this function
void func(int arg1) {
    PrintF

    // some dummy calculation inside this function

    int aa[100]; // 400 Bytes
    for(int i = 0;i<100;i++) {
        if(i%20 == 0) {
            aa[i] = 2*i;
        }
    }

    // on return from this function
    // ret instruction will be called
    // due to which rip will point to the value of 
    // top 8 byte of childStack
    // which is basically sched function
}
```

GDB disassembly shows that the argument `int arg1` is expected in the lower `32` bits of `%rdi`.

```
Dump of assembler code for function func(int):
   0x0000000000000a69 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000000a6a <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000000a6d <+4>: sub    $0x1c0,%rsp
   0x0000000000000a74 <+11>:    mov    %edi,-0x1b4(%rbp)
```

If I try with three arguments as in `void func(int arg1,int arg2,int agr3)` then

```
   0x0000000000000a74 <+11>:    mov    %edi,-0x1b4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000000a7a <+17>:    mov    %esi,-0x1b8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000000a80 <+23>:    mov    %edx,-0x1bc(%rbp)
```

I also found online that, in `x86_64` arguments are passed on stack also (sometimes, I am not sure about this).

My question is how to pass arguments to `func` reliably ? Do I need to manually copy arguments into `rdi`,`rsi` and `rdx` as we did for context switch? What about more number of arguments and other types of arguments like `reference type` for example `lvalue reference` or `rvalue reference` in C++?

Thanks!

Comment: Consult ABI documentation for the particular details, they aren't pretty. The usual trick is to pass a single `void*` argument which the callee can then use to access a `struct` if needed to get more arguments.

Comment: and this `void*` can always be loaded in `%rdi` in `x86_64`??

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Mostly void* should contain pointers to dynamically allocated variables. Or even better smart pointers. Since the thread from which you start the thread could quit the scope. It is better using std::shared_ptr for this kind of thing.

Comment: This is not something you want to do yourself. There is not a standard ABI so anytiing you do is locked to what you are working on. What you are looking for is co-routines. They are in boost and I also think they are in the latest version of the standard C++20 (though I would check that).

Comment: Yes, I am actually aware of coroutine in C++20. I want to get the minimal possible basic implementation idea of coroutine before we start learning C++20's raw coroutine APIs.

Comment: [names with double underscores are reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/995714) so don't use `const int __stack_size`